# Why use UniqueTogetherValidator over Django's default validation behavior?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model defined with a `unique_together` relationship defined between `name` and `address`, shown below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'address')
```

I also have a Django REST Framework serializer with a `UniqueTogetherValidator` describing the same constraint as defined in the model, shown below:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = (
            'name', 'address',
        )
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Branch.objects.all(),
                fields=['name', 'address']
            )
        ]
```

While testing this constraint, I noticed that the exact same behavior is exhibited whether or not I have the `UniqueTogetherValidator` added to the PersonSerializer. The same error message is returned whether or not I include this (due to the `unique_together` defined on the model).

My question is: what is the reason for explicitly declaring validators on the serializer if the behavior is performed behind the scenes? I did notice you can change the error message, but this seems like quite a bit of boilerplate for solely manipulating an error message for violating a `unique_together` constraint. Is there a broader reason for utilizing these validator classes that I'm missing?

Comment: I am facing a problem that this not work with multi column unique indexes that have a nullable column. So I am thinking of inherit from this validator and do my custom one. That can be added to the list of why.. to let us do custom behaviour. Also because of what docstring says at the begining of the file : https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/validators.py